# how can i get rows with similar column value

Tags: sql-server-2000

how can i get rows with similar column value

Comment: Can you add some more information?  Is your column a number or string, etc.?

Comment: my column is a number..i just want to get the rows which hava the duplcacy for this column..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to find rows that have the same value in a column as another row in the same table?

```
SELECT columName FROM tablename GROUP BY columnName HAVING COUNT(columnName) > 1
```

Edit:

If you want to get all the rows with a non-unique value in the column, you can use the above query in an IN clause:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE columnName IN (
    SELECT columName FROM tablename 
    GROUP BY columnName 
    HAVING COUNT(columnName) > 1
)
```

The inner query will find all the column values that are duplicated, and the outer query will return all the rows that have matching column values.